# RPC Runtime Errors With Metamask

Tags: metamask, ganache, rpc

Im trying to create a basic product list/buy/sell form locally. While trying to run a transaction on Metamask I get a console error with this stack:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert","code":-32000,"data":{"0x0d09d04fe1bb5ae95f317da347e180514d3e7bbbe71998eb60e778b986b95afb":{"error":"revert","program_counter":48,"return":"0x"},"stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}'
```

I am running on localhost I have started restarting everything -
Truffle, Ganache, Chrome, the App - but in vain.
Any ideas?

Transaction Function:
I am trying to add a product. Heres my smart contract method :

```
function createProduct(string memory _name, uint _price) public { 
 //Make sure parameters are correct 
 require(bytes(_name).length > 0); 
 require(_price > 0); 
 //Increment Product Count productCount++; 
 //Create the product 
 products[productCount] = Product(productCount, _name, _price, 
  msg.sender, false); 
 //Trigger an event 
 emit ProductCreated(productCount, _name, _price, msg.sender, false); }
```

Heres how Im calling it within my app:

```
createProduct(name, price) {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.state.marketplace.methods.createProduct(name, price).send({ from:this.state.account })
      .once('receipt', (receipt) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      })
  }
```

Comment: The error is in the contract. Post your transaction function

Comment: I am trying to add a product. Heres my smart contract method :

 function  createProduct(string memory _name, uint _price) public {
  //Make sure parameters are correct
  require(bytes(_name).length > 0);
  require(_price > 0);
  //Increment Product Count
  productCount++;
  //Create the product
  products[productCount] = Product(productCount, _name, _price, msg.sender, false);
  
  //Trigger an event
  emit ProductCreated(productCount, _name, _price, msg.sender, false);
 }

Comment: Heres how Im calling it within my app:

createProduct(name, price) {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.state.marketplace.methods.createProduct(name, price).send({ from:this.state.account })
      .once('receipt', (receipt) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      })

  }

Comment: @shrew-tea What's `products`? There's nothing obvious, perhaps you have the wrong address, abi, or using an old copy of the contract.